# Can’t assign delegate an anonymous method with less specific parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, c#-2.0

```
public class Program
{
    delegate void Srini(string param);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Srini sr = new Srini(PrintHello1);
        sr += new Srini(PrintHello2);      //case 2:      
        sr += new Srini(delegate(string o) { Console.WriteLine(o); });
        sr += new Srini(delegate(object o) { Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()); }); //case 4:
        sr += new Srini(delegate { Console.WriteLine(“This line is accepted,though the method signature is not Comp”); });//case 5
        sr("Hello World");
        Console.Read();
    }       

    static void PrintHello1(string  param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param);
    }

    static void PrintHello2(object param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param);
    }
}
```

Compiler doesn't complain about the case 2 (see the comment), well, the reason is straight forward since string inherits from object. Along the same lines, why is it complaining for anonymous method types (see the comment //case 4:) that

> Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type 'DelegateTest.Program.Srini' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

where as in case of normal method it doesn't? Or am I comparing apples with oranges?
Another case is why is it accepting anonymous method without parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method group conversions support variance (as of C# 2 - they didn't in C# 1), anonymous function conversions simply don't. Given that whenever you write an anonymous function you *can* write the appropriate parameter, why not just do so? There would be no benefit in allowing variance there as far as I can see, and it would make the rules harder to get right. (Variance ends up being pretty complex in the spec.)

EDIT: An anonymous method without a parameter list is basically compatible with any delegate's parameter list so long as it doesn't have `out` parameters. Basically it's a way of saying, "I don't care about the parameters." It's the *one* feature of anonymous methods that lambda expressions don't have :)

Comment: Oops jon,it's a typo;it's without.I am referring to //case 5 .i have edited the question.

Comment: @Srinivas: Okay, I've edited the answer appropriately.